# How to open file in same VSCode window instance tab after opening folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I tried to open folder first in new VScode window and then open file in same VScode window, but the folder is opening and the file is not opening. For reference I tried like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44123722/vscode-opening-a-folder-and-a-file-from-the-same-routine).
It will be great if you provide any suggestion to handle this case.

Here is my code, how i tried.

**Case1**: Only folder is opening.

```js
let uri =  vscode.Uri.file(apiPath);
await vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.openFolder", uri, {
     forceNewWindow: true,
}).then(async function(){
     let filePath = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(apiPath, "Abc.java"));
     await vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.open", filePath);
})
```

**Case2**: Both folder and file is opening but in different VScode windows.

```js
let uri =  vscode.Uri.file(apiPath);
await vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.openFolder", uri, {
     forceNewWindow: true,
});

let filePath = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(apiPath, "Abc.java"));
await vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.open", filePath);
```